# Can't establish wss connection [React + ASP.NET Core, SignalR + nginx]

Tags: c#, reactjs, nginx, websocket, signalr

I have React app that talks to Asp.Net core API. Both of them are deployed on Docker on my VM. Nginx is installed and configured to resolve domain names for app (thesis.uno - for react app, api.thesis.uno - for asp.net core api)

I added chat support to my app using SignalR, but when react tries to establish wss connection through api.thesis.uno it fails
[image]

When I replace api domain name with VM ip and port, everything seems to function properly, which means that the trouble is in the Nginx configuration.

[image]

I tried to google this trouble, but no solution seemed to help me ([SignalR in ASP.NET Core behind Nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48300288/signalr-in-asp-net-core-behind-nginx), [NGINX to reverse proxy websockets AND enable SSL (wss://)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102110/nginx-to-reverse-proxy-websockets-and-enable-ssl-wss))

My nginx config:

```json
client_max_body_size 64M;

upstream backend {
    # enable sticky session based on IP
    ip_hash;

    server localhost:5000;
  }

server {
    root /var/www/thesis.uno/html; # Directly serves anything in the Rails public folder
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name thesis.uno www.thesis.uno; # managed by Certbot

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5001;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/thesis.uno/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/thesis.uno/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = www.thesis.uno) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = thesis.uno) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen 80 ;
    server_name thesis.uno www.thesis.uno;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    server_name api.thesis.uno www.api.thesis.uno;

    # all other requests
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }

    # web socket chat requests
    location /api/chat {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.thesis.uno/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.thesis.uno/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = www.api.thesis.uno) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = api.thesis.uno) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen 80;
    server_name api.thesis.uno www.api.thesis.uno;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

UPDATE:

Turned out nginx has a logs file, seems like nginx can't redirect request properly, gives 404 on request

[image]

Comment: If there is anything suspicious you see in my configs, please point it out. I am still learning :)

Answer (score 0):

Your Nginx configuration is wrong, it is missing the setting to connect to **WS** protocol.

```
location /api/chat {
    ---
    ---
}
```

It should connect to **ws** protocol, I suggest you to read more about the topic.

Here is a working example in test condition, hope this helps you.

```
upstream channels-backend {
    server localhost:8000;
    # here you connect your channel ip:port
}


server {
    server_name  example.com www.example.com;
        location /static/ {
        }
        location /media {
        }
        location / {
            include proxy_params;
            proxy_pass http://unix:/yourGunicorn.sock;
            # This is for Nginx connection to gunicorn
        }

        # this is where your chat server connection takes place.
        location /ws/ {
            try_files $uri @proxy_for_websocket;
            # websocket connection comes with ws
        }
        location @proxy_for_websocket {
            proxy_pass http://channels-backend;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }
        listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on;
        listen 443 ssl;
        # Your certificate detail here
}
```

**WSS** is the secured WebSocket connection, try connecting with **ws** and later convert that to **wss**.

Comment: unfortunately that didnt help, something trickier is going on

Comment: But you should use ws protocoal in nginx for websocket :)

Comment: There can be many issues like your upstream is not running, what is the error message?