# SignalR: The server returned status code '200' when status code '101' was expected

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, websocket, signalr

i want to connect my maui blazor app (windows) via signalR to the .net blazor server app so i can push the messages from server to clients. I tested it with wpf dekstop app also, the result is the same, handshake failed.

Version that i am using: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client" Version="6.0.1" and i tried 7.0.1.

The funny thing is, @localhost everything is working fine. And the blazor wasm has signalR fully functional with the same server.

Server side is hosted @akamai

Details of the error message:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection: Trace: Waiting on Connection Lock in StartAsyncInner (/_/src/SignalR/clients/csharp/Client.Core/src/HubConnection.cs:247).
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection: Trace: The HubConnection is attempting to transition from the Disconnected state to the Connecting state.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection: Debug: Starting HubConnection.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection: Debug: Starting HttpConnection.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection: Debug: Establishing connection with server at 'https://staging.vetat.work/hub/printertool'.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.LoggingHttpMessageHandler: Trace: Sending HTTP request POST 'https://staging.asd/hub/printertool/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1'.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection: Debug: Established connection 'B07mkUpGtdoEwG6C9uQZbA' with the server.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection: Debug: Starting transport 'WebSockets' with Url: https://staging.vetat.work/hub/printertool.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport: Information: Starting transport. Transfer mode: Text. Url: 'wss://staging.vetat.work/hub/printertool?id=UGcgq9uJEOL5hZkA1iZxCQ'.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection: Error: Failed to start connection. Error starting transport 'WebSockets'.

System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketException (0x80004005): The server returned status code '200' when status code '101' was expected.
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketHandle.ValidateResponse(HttpResponseMessage response, String secValue, ClientWebSocketOptions options)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketHandle.ConnectAsync(Uri uri, HttpMessageInvoker invoker, CancellationToken cancellationToken, ClientWebSocketOptions options)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.ClientWebSocket.ConnectAsyncCore(Uri uri, HttpMessageInvoker invoker, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport.DefaultWebSocketFactory(WebSocketConnectionContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport.StartAsync(Uri url, TransferFormat transferFormat, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.StartTransport(Uri connectUrl, HttpTransportType transportType, TransferFormat transferFormat, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection: Debug: Skipping transport WebSockets because it failed to initialize.

System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketException (0x80004005): The server returned status code '200' when status code '101' was expected.
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketHandle.ValidateResponse(HttpResponseMessage response, String secValue, ClientWebSocketOptions options)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketHandle.ConnectAsync(Uri uri, HttpMessageInvoker invoker, CancellationToken cancellationToken, ClientWebSocketOptions options)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.ClientWebSocket.ConnectAsyncCore(Uri uri, HttpMessageInvoker invoker, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport.DefaultWebSocketFactory(WebSocketConnectionContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport.StartAsync(Uri url, TransferFormat transferFormat, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.StartTransport(Uri connectUrl, HttpTransportType transportType, TransferFormat transferFormat, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.SelectAndStartTransport(TransferFormat transferFormat, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection: Debug: Establishing connection with server at 'https://staging.asd/hub/printertool'.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.LoggingHttpMessageHandler: Trace: Sending HTTP request POST 'https://staging.asd/hub/printertool/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1'.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection: Debug: Established connection 'trPpDN3vsUzTTUqSu0LdwQ' with the server.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection: Debug: Starting transport 'ServerSentEvents' with Url: https://staging.asd/hub/printertool.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.ServerSentEventsTransport: Information: Starting transport. Transfer mode: Text.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.LoggingHttpMessageHandler: Trace: Sending HTTP request GET 'https://staging.asd/hub/printertool?id=snz3w-l4JZ8sYDtO8cK9jQ'.
```

I tried maui app, i tried debugging, logging, wpf app also. I expect that i can send a message from server to clients.

```
   var url = _configuration[MauiConstants.AppConfig.SignalR];

        _connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .WithUrl(url, options =>
            {
                options.AccessTokenProvider = () => Task.FromResult(token);
            })
            .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
            {
                // Log to the Console
                logging.AddDebug();

                // This will set ALL logging to Debug level
                logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace);
            })
            .WithAutomaticReconnect()
            .Build();
```

For authorization i am using bearer token

This is the server config:

```
if (config.SignalR.AllowCors)
    {
        _ = app.UseCors(builder =>
          {
              _ = builder.AllowAnyMethod()
                         .AllowAnyHeader()
                         .AllowCredentials()
                         .WithOrigins(config.SignalR.CorsAddress)
                         .SetIsOriginAllowedToAllowWildcardSubdomains();
          });
    }


_ = authenticationBuilder.AddJwtBearer(AuthConstant.Scheme.PrinterTool, options =>
    {
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        options.SaveToken = true;
        options.Audience = $"{Audience.PrinterTool:G}";
        var signingKey = Convert.FromBase64String(secretKey);
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            AuthenticationType = AuthConstant.Scheme.PrinterTool,
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(signingKey),
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Convert.ToDouble(config.AdminAppAuthentication.ExpiresIn))
        };

        options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
        {
            OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
            {
                if (context.Exception.GetType() == typeof(SecurityTokenExpiredException))
                {
                    context.Response.Headers["Token-Expired"] = "true";
                }

                return Task.CompletedTask;
            },
            OnMessageReceived = context =>
            {
                //If the request is for our hub
                var path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;

                if (path.StartsWithSegments(config.SignalR.PrinterToolMainHubRoute))
                {
                    var authorization = context.Request.Headers?.Authorization.FirstOrDefault(a => a.StartsWith("Bearer "));
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(authorization))
                    {
                        context.Token = authorization.Substring("Bearer ".Length);
                    }
                }

                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        };
    });
```

Comment: HTTP has two modes 1) Version 1.0 is steam mode where you get one response 2) Version 1.1 which is chunk mode.  After each chunk is receive you have to send a next chunk message.  There is a different between HTTPClient (version 1.0 and 1.1) and HTTPSocket.  They are not compatible.  HTTPClient after each request/response the connection closes.  HTTPSocket the connection stays open until closed.  Status 101 indicates the connection switches from HTTP Client to HTTP Socket.  It looks like the server didn't support Web socket and made request/response using HTTP Client.

Comment: @jdweng
but how does it work between wasm and blazor server then, when the server does not support web socket? I use the same logic for my maui app.

Comment: There are cases where a relay is used in code that has two ports (two connections) 1) HttpClient 2) HTTP Socket Then messages are relayed from one connection to the other.

Comment: @jdweng what solution do you propose?

Comment: There is a difference between the localhost server and the deployed server.  Do not know why.  From exception it appears it may be HTTP Client vs WebSocket.  You need to find out why the local server and deployed server are different.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that this issue was already resolved.
I had the same issue, and I resolved changing the nginx configuration on prod server

Changing this:

```
proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
```

by this:

```
proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;
```

complete nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    server_name api.your-domain.com;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains" always;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/live/your-domain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/live/your-domain.com/privkey.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://172.17.0.1:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_headers_hash_max_size 512;
        proxy_headers_hash_bucket_size 128;
    }
}
```

source: [SignalR in ASP.NET Core behind Nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48300288/signalr-in-asp-net-core-behind-nginx)